# Why does the Linux kernel #define a symbol as itself?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

In the Linux kernel, [there can be found a line of code](https://github.com/Constellation/linux-3.10.17/blob/master/arch/blackfin/include/uapi/asm/swab.h) that looks redundant to me:

```
#define __arch_swahb32 __arch_swahb32
```

What is the purpose of an idiom like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
#ifdef foo
    foo();
#endif
```

If you want a snippet like the above to call function `foo`, you need to define `foo`. However, if you just

```
#define foo
```

then the function `foo` name will be replaced with an empty token, and the first snippet is preprocessed to just `();`. If, however, you

```
#define foo foo
```

then the first snippet will preprocess to `foo();` as it should.

Answer (score 6):

Trick to ensure `#if defined(__arch_swahb32)` passes but doesn't replace. (Often used to implement macro type functions)