# define a macro symbol to itself

Tags: c, linux-kernel

In Linux kernel, many places I saw code like the following:

```
#ifndef __raw_readl
#define __raw_readl __raw_readl
static inline u32 __raw_readl(const volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    return *(const volatile u32 __force *)addr;
}
#endif
```

What is the purpose of the line `#define __raw_readl __raw_readl`?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41018115/4390699) but what I understood is it's needed when we don't want a symbol to be replaced with blank. Still the above case is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the macro is *not* defined to itself.

The preprocessor is a quite simple search-n-replace engine. It collects all the `#define`s, and when it parses through the source it looks for defined words. If it finds one it replaces that word with all the text defined right of this word.

There are some rules for recursion but I'd like to leave the research for that as an exercise for you; and it doesn't matter here.

So the `#define` you show will simply replace `__raw_readl` with the very same word.

---

What is the reasoning behind that, now?

For this, just think what will happen if `__raw_readl` *is* already defined (as a preprocessor macro, that is important!) when the source shown is handled.

The `#ifndef` will evaluate to `false` and all lines until `#endif` will be ignored.

So one can provide any other implementation of `__raw_readl()` and to make it effective `#define` the macro `__raw_readl`.

But if there is no such macro the `#ifndef` evaluates to `true` and this source provides the shown implementation.

You might like to think about this as some kind of "default."

---

The best thing to get some idea how it works is to experiment. Write some source and see what the preprocessor produces. You might like to learn about the option `-E` of GCC which stops the compiling right after the preprocessor's work. Look it up in the documentation.

---

*Disclaimer: I never waded through kernel sources, and my explanation might be erroneous. Please correct me, and at best edit this answer.*

Comment: But what would happen if we remove the `#define __raw_readl __raw_readl`? Is there any error in that case?

Comment: There will be no difference *as long as this part of the source is not read again*. Most probably you found it in a header file, and those can be included as often as one wants. There are other measures to handle such cases, too, so I see it as a safety net.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef __raw_readl
//put code here
#endif
```

This means that the section is only activated if `__raw_readl` is not yet defined.
So you can force defining something only once even if the file is included multiple times.

```
#define __raw_readl __raw_readl
```

This means that `__raw_readl` is always replaced by `__raw_readl`

```
static inline u32 __raw_readl(const volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    return *(const volatile u32 __force *)addr;
}
```

Here `__raw_readl` is replaced by `__raw_readl` like defined above.
So the whole code is saying that if `__raw_readl` is not defined, put the function called `__raw_readl` in place.